# tail -f, insert line break after log is idle for 3 seconds?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, tail

When doing a `tail -f error.log`, how to insert programmatically a line break after nothing has been appened to the file for 3 seconds ?

(obviously, once one line break has been added, no other line break should be added until other line(s) of text is added to the log file)

For instance, these lines are appened to error.log :

```
foo
bar
boo [[wait 4 seconds]]
2far
2foo
2bar
2boo [[wait 40 seconds]]
2far
```

This would be the output in the console :

```
foo
bar
boo

2far
2foo
2bar
2boo

2far
```

Comment: You could probably adapt my function in https://askubuntu.com/a/993821/158442, or use `ts` to add timestamping to the output and process the timestamps

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you're doing it interactively, you can just hit the enter key a bunch of times.  :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could always implement the `tail -f` (well here, unless you uncomment the `seek()`,  more like `tail -n +1 -f` as we're dumping the whole file) by hand with `perl` for instance:

```
perl -e '
  $| = 1;
  # seek STDIN, 0, 2; # uncomment if you want to skip the text that is
                      # already there. Or if using the ksh93 shell, add
                      # a <((EOF)) after < your-file
  while (1) {
    if ($_ = <STDIN>) {
      print; $t = 0
    } else {
      print "\n"            if $t == 3;
      # and a line of "-"s after 10 seconds:
      print "-" x 72 . "\n" if $t == 10;
      sleep 1;
      $t++;
    }
  }' < your-file
```

Or let `tail -f` do the tailing and use `perl` to insert the newlines if there's no input for 3 seconds:

```
tail -f file | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$SIG{ALRM} = sub {print "\n"}} alarm 3'
```

Those assume that the output itself is not slowed down (like when the output goes to a pipe that is not actively read).

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out why the second one actually works :)

Comment: I've tried the first one, and it printed ALL the files before hand, so it isn't optimal. The second one works like a charm. I have added the "tail -n 0  -f $1 |" option (-n 0) to avoid displaying the old lines of files.

Comment: Small question : How could I amend the second solution to display an additional line of dashes (-------) after 10 seconds ? (I have tried multiple ways, but cannot make anything work)

Comment: @Cedric, see edit for your first point. Your second requirement would be easier with the first approach.

Answer (score 8):

**`bash`** + **`date`** solution:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do        
    prev=$t         # get previous timestamp value
    t=$(date +%s)   # get current timestamp value
    [[ ! -z "$prev" ]] && [[ "$((t-prev))" -ge 3 ]] && echo ""
    echo "$line"    # print current line
done < <(tail -f error.log)
```

Comment: In Bash, you can use `$SECONDS` to count time intervals. I think it's the number of seconds since the shell started, not that it matters when taking a difference.

Comment: @ilkkachu, or `read -t` or `$TMOUT`. `$SECONDS` is broken in `bash` and `mksh`. `time bash -c 'while ((SECONDS < 3)); do :; done'` will last in between 2 and 3 seconds. Better to use zsh or ksh93 instead here (with `typeset -F SECONDS`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I don't think it's any different than using `date +%s`. Both give the time in full seconds, which does have the effect that the interval from, say, 1.9 to 4.0 looks like 3 full seconds, even though it's really 2.1. It's hard to work around that if all you can't access the fractional seconds. But yes, they should probably sleep here instead of busylooping, and then `read -t` could just as well be used. Even if you do sleep manually, `time bash -c 'while [[ $SECONDS -lt 3 ]]; do sleep 1; done'` works just fine.

Comment: ksh93 and zsh are OK with that (zsh used not to). Even with integer $SECONDS, setting `SECONDS=0` ensures that `$SECONDS` will reach 1 in exactly 1 second. That's not the case with `bash` as it uses `time()` to track `$SECONDS` instead of `gettimeofday()`. I reported bugs to mksh, zsh and bash some time ago, only zsh was fixed. (good point about the issue being the same with `date +%s`). Note that it's not a busyloop here, as we're reading from the output of `tail -f` over a pipe.

Comment: +1 and Bash has a "shortcut" using the built-in `printf` to emulate `date` without external tools or command substitution: `printf -v t '%(%s)T' -1`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: `printf -v VAR` writes the result directly into the shell variable name `VAR`, which is what your code does with the output of `date` too. Of course you can also use `t=$(printf '%(%s)T' -1)` at the cost of a process substitution.

Answer (score 6):

**`Python`** solution (with dynamic *time gap* argument):

`tailing_by_time.py` script:

```
import time, sys

t_gap = int(sys.argv[1])    # time gap argument
ts = 0
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()    # get/read current line from stdin
    curr_ts = time.time()                  # get current timestamp
    if ts and curr_ts - ts >= t_gap:
        print("")                          # print empty line/newline
    ts = curr_ts
    if line:
        print(line)                        # print current line if it's not empty
```

---

Usage:

```
tail -f error.log | python tailing_by_time.py 3
```